# Finding out if a game-state has occurred before, int[5][5] with 3 different values, 0 1 2

Tags: java

I am trying to find a good way to find if a game state has occurred before. I was thinking about creating an own hash-map with an own hash-function based on the index of the array multiplied by the index numbers of the cells, but maybe there is a better way I did not think of yet?

It's very rare to get into the same game-state and often only the order changes. This is an example of my game-state representative which is a `int[5][5]`:

```
[2][1][2][2][2]
[2][2][2][2][0]
[1][2][2][0][2]
[2][0][2][2][2]
[2][2][1][2][1]
```

Often I try to first come up with a few ideas before I get on Stack-Overflow but now I have no clue about what is efficient. The odds of a game-state happening twice is very rare.

Comment: What are the different values each array field can have?

Comment: 0 1 and 2. 2 means empty, 1 means a piece type X, 0 means a piece type Y. In the beginning of the game it's mostly empty, like in this example. Later it's common to only have a few open spots left.

I think the average game has between 5- a few thousand different gameStates. With mostly around 100-200 gameStates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `3^25` game states. Just like a 2-value board can be represented as a binary number, your 3-value board can be represented as a ternary number. Concatenate your 2d array into a single string using a pair of for loops. You'll get:

```
String state = "2122222220122022022222121";
```

Then convert that into a long, using base 3:

```
long longState = Long.valueOf(state, 3); // 753111582406
```

Store the long in a `HashSet<Long>`, and check against that every time you run into a new state using the procedure above.

Comment: This seems like an easy and efficient way. Thank you.

Comment: Nice idea. @Joop if your game does not have a direction (i.e. there is no "top"), you should also consider all possible 90° rotations of the board.

Comment: @isnot2bad any idea on how you would do this if you would indeed use a number representation of a gamestate?

Comment: @Joop use 4 different orderings of for loops (swap i and j, count from last to 0 - you'd need to think of exactly how) in order to generate 4 different strings. Or more, if you want board positions flipped, as well.

Comment: @mk As you will have to write a for-loop anyway, you could directly convert the board into long as follows: `for(int i = board.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) { state = state * 3 + board[i]; }`. That's even easier than using an intermediate `String` representation.

Answer (score 1):

Every field in your array can have one of three different values `{0, 1, 2}`. So if you use two bits per array field, you can encode your game state using a 50 bit sequence which easily fits into a variable of type `long`.

That's an example of how to encode your game state (to make it simpler I just assume your board is a one-dimensional array of 25 elements):

```
public long encode(int[] board) {
    long state = 0;
    for (int i = board.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        state += board[i];
        state <<= 2;
    }
}
```

Of course instead of doing a one-time encoding of your game state you can also easily update your state every time an array field changes:

```
public long update(int[] board, int newValue, long state) {
    board[i] = newValue;
    // now update the corresponding bits
    int pos = i * 2;
    state ^= ((state ^ (newValue << pos)) & (0x3 << pos));
}
```

It is also possible to restore the game board by decoding the state.